# How Would You Animate a 3d Characters Face (With Textures)

Tags: textures, 3d-meshes

So I'd like to do a low poly style of modeling, and one of the corners I'd like to cut is on head geometry. Specifically, making the details of the face a texture (like a Mii or a character in Animal Crossing for example).

How would you go about accomplishing animating the face? Getting it onto the model in the first place?

I'm using Unreal Engine to learn and working on my 3d modeling skills at the same time, so knowing a general workflow would give me some structure to work with.